# Sumo/Veins not spawning all vehicles

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am using Omnet, SUmo and Veins to simulate Vanets. The issue I face is that with certain maps, not all cars in the route file are spawned, at least not when they are supposed to. From what I understand it is because there is "not enough space in the network". I find it weird because the map I currently have covers 5*4 Manhattan blocks and should be big enough to accommodate thirty vehicles.

When I use departLane and departPos with "free", cars spawn, but the simulation fails randomly. I used a much bigger map with thirty vehicles and that one worked fine.

Any ideas, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

At depart time SUMO does not check for general space in the network but on the given departLane (which defaults to the rightmost usable lane) of the first edge in the route that's why vehicles are delayed. You already found out what to do against it, use `departLane="free"`.

As for the second problem please give at least the error message preferrably with a more detailled description and the SUMO version.

Comment: Thank you. The simulation failing was another problem entirely. The issue I have is that even when I use departLane="free", not all cars are spawned. For example with 60 cars only 57 are spawned. On the same map with 150 cars, only about 120 are spawned. I understand that the cars will show up later on during the simulation, but why am I getting only 57 when the map can spawn at least 120 at the start

Comment: Because it is not the entire map sumo looks at. If you have a single edge which is crowded, it will cause delays for all vehicles which want to be inserted there. Or do all cars use the same insertion edge?

Comment: I don't think so, as I have created random routes, they spawn on different edgeq/roads

Comment: Random does still not mean equally distributed. Did you use randomTrips?